# Facebook user image not showing on <img> tag

Tags: html, node.js, facebook, ejs

I have a .ejs page with this piece of code

```
<li><% if(userInfo.image=="" || userInfo.image==null || userInfo.image==undefined){ %>
    <img src="/assets/img/default.png" class="img-responsive pic-bordered" alt="" /><%}else{%>
    <img src="
        <%= userInfo.image%>" class="img-responsive pic-bordered" alt="" /><%}%>
</li>
```

The userInfo.image value is "http://graph.facebook.com/xxx728122636xxxx/picture?redirect=true&width=432&height=432"
but the image doesn't show.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/f6dsp3wd/1/

**Edit**
Ok i figured out. This computer im working on has a extension on its browsers named "Ghostery" that was blocking the display of facebook image

you can close this

Comment: What does the outputted HTML look like? Could you add that into your question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f6dsp3wd/1/ something like this

Comment: In your example the image loads up fine?

Comment: ok i figured out. This computer im working on has a extension on its browsers named "Ghostery" that was blocking the display of facebook image

Answer (score 0):

Try with `https://graph.facebook.com/<%= userInfo.id %>/picture?type=square`.

Comment: userInfo.id, inst the facebook id, it is the id from our API

Comment: OK. Try to use user's Facebook ID. This should work.