# vuetify doesnt load image in <v-img> although prop shows it has the url

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

```
<v-img :src="getPhoto()"  height="200px" width="200px"></v-img>
```

this is for photo to load from getphot function. the src has the url for facebook but vuetify doesnt load anything [image]

```
computed: {
  user () {
    return this.$store.getters.user
  }
},
methods: {
  getPhoto () {
    return this.$store.getters.user.photoUrl
  }
}
```

i do not get any error. and when i use the link i can access the image. because i have logged in from my device.
note: i am using firebase for all of these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<v-img :src="require('getPhoto()')"  height="200px" width="200px"></v-img>
```

instead of

```
<v-img :src="getPhoto()"  height="200px" width="200px"></v-img>
```

> Vue loader converts relative paths into require functions automatically for you. Unfortunately, this is not the case when it comes to custom components. You can circumvent this issue by using require. If you're using Vuetify as a Vue-CLI 3 plugin, you can edit your project's vue.config.js file by modifying the options for vue-loader.

```
// Incorrect
<v-img src="../path/to/img" />

// Correct
<v-img :src="require('../path/to/img')" />
```

Source: [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#relative-images-are-not-working-in-v-card-v-img-and-other-custom-vuetify-components)

**Update:** When not using a relative path, I tried creating an example when using a function to get the `URL` for the image source. I think there are two problems with your code:

1. Remove the `()` from `getPhoto()` in `<v-img>`
2. Add the `getPhoto()` to the **computed** property.

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/QPoqLM?editors=1010)

I hope it helps.

Comment: i get error "this dependency is not found" for require('getPhoto()'). also my image link is of facebook. there is no relative url.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878344/facebook-user-image-not-showing-on-img-tag 
in addition to ur solution i tried this. it didnt work either. im sorry

Comment: ok now I found out that the image from facebook didn't show up in chrome but did in Microsoft edge for some reason. anyways u helped me figure the solution of vuetify problem. I am going to tick it as answer.